# How to temporarily disable accounts in outlook (pop3 & smtp)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp, pop3

One can easily disable pop3 accounts in outlook (2019) by not including the account in a send/receive group. However, this still attempts to connect to the account's smtp server. When an email provider is having issues (as gmail  is as I am writing this), this smtp connection attempt causes an error dialog to come up in outlook. Outlook won't let me save the account if I just remove the smtp server from the account properties. I have other outlook accounts that I don't want disabled, and of course I want pop3 polling/sending with smtp to continue as usual for those accounts. How do I disable both stmp & pop3 for an outlook account without deleting it and without affecting other outlook accounts?

Comment: I have 3 POP accounts on two machines - Office 365.  I do not include 2 of these accounts in Send / Receive (Send / Receive Groups, Define Send / Receive Groups). So there is no receive and while send may be active, it does not do anything.  So there should be no harm in just unchecking the accounts you do not want in Send / Receive Groups.

Comment: @John Like I said, "When an email provider is having issues (as gmail is as I am writing this), this smtp connection attempt causes an error dialog to come up in outlook."; that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I spent some time on the Send / Receive groups but I do not see any way to turn this right off.  Outlook can be set to send before receive and I think this action may be built in.

Comment: It seems that we could only get here (just as what you have tested) with the built-in options in Outlook desktop client alone.